# OkHttp client authentication failing to validate server and send client certificate in the same request

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

### I keep editing this question as I dig further into it.

EDIT
I'm able to build my OkHttp client to where it includes both the client cert in the Client.SSLContext.KeyManager, and the trusted certs in the Client.SSLContext.TrustManager

```
// Create keyManagerFactory with keystore.jks
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("keystore.jks")), storePassword.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(clientStore, storePassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        
// Create trustManagerFactory with default cacerts truststore
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                                                + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }
trustManager = trustManagers[0];

// Create sslContext from keyManagers (from custom keystore with client key) and default trustManagers
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
defaultFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

okClient = new OkHttpClient
                 .Builder()
                 .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManager)
                 .build();
```

However, my client still isn't sending my client certificate (server cert is validated through the trust store successfully). Getting this in the ssl debug logs

```
No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
```

Here's what my SSLContext looks like on the HttpClient. [image]
Seems like that should send the client cert named "cureskeystore" in the request?

`keystore.jks` is built with the following commands

```
openssl pkcs12 -export \
        -name curesKeyStore \
        -in clientCert.crt \
        -inkey privateKey.pem \
        -certfile clientCert.crt \
        -out chain.p12 \
        -passout pass:${STORE_PASSWORD}

keytool -importkeystore \
        -srckeystore chain.p12 \
        -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
        -destkeystore keystore.jks \
        -deststoretype pkcs12 \
        -storepass ${STORE_PASSWORD} \
        -srcstorepass ${STORE_PASSWORD} > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have also tried creating a store with the client cert + `-CAfile` with the root and intermediate certs:

```
# client cert with CAcerts included
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain \
        -in clientCert.crt \
        -inkey privateKey.pem \
        -out keystore.p12 \
        -name p12KeyStore \
        -CAfile caCerts.crt \
        -caname root \
        -passout pass:${STORE_PASSWORD}

keytool -importkeystore \
        -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
        -destkeystore keystore.jks \
        -srckeystore keystore.p12 \
        -alias p12KeyStore \
        -storepass ${STORE_PASSWORD} \
        -srcstorepass ${STORE_PASSWORD}
```

---

Another possible issue is the CertificateRequest not matching my client certificate.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:671|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [ecdsa_sign, rsa_sign, dss_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [redacted, but does not include Entrust]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.619 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.620 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.621 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.621 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.621 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.621 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|XNIO-1 task-1|2021-10-18 11:07:18.621 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:774|No available authentication scheme
```

My certificate's signing algorithm is `SHA256withRSA`. Is that not the same as `rsa_pkcs1_sha256`?
Also, my client certificate is signed by Entrust, which is not listed in the certificate authorities for the server's CertificateRequest.

EDIT: I made some requests to a different HTTPS server that does not include `certificate authorities` in its CertificateRequest to the client. I verified that SSL can find the expected client certificate and sends it back to the server as expected. So it seems like this is an issue with the server request not including my CA in their list of accepted `certificate authorities`. Reaching out to the server to request an update.

Comment: *"they all seem to be regarding self-signed certs."* - they are not. They are also about misconfigured servers which for example do not send all intermediate certificates. They are also about servers which send the wrong certificate since the client does not use SNI. Unfortunately it is unknown what the problem is in your case since not enough information are provided to reproduce or debug the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich added the client code for the http request. Not really sure what would be helpful here without posting the actual certificate data from `Djavax.net.debug=all`.

Comment: Given that this is about server certificate validation I doubt that the problem can be debugged without knowing the actual server and how you access it. All the client certificate stuff is not needed since it fails before even using the client certificate.

Comment: sslContext.init takes an array of trust managers. How about passing it your custom manager first and then the default manager (that has all the standard certs)? Alternatively you can just import the root cert you need to trust into your own custom trust store.

Comment: Thanks @ewramner, I'm messing around with the sslContext.init right now. I tried adding my custom keystore as a keystoreManager into `sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);` where `keyManagers` is from my custom keystore and `trustManagers` is from my default truststore (cacerts). I'll try to implement your suggestion to add them both as trustManagers.

Comment: Trying to avoid adding the server root cert into my custom keystore. That doesn't seem like best practice? I'll keep it as a last resort option though.

Comment: @ewramner editing the question to better reflect my current issue. Adding both trust managers (one from Keystore, one from Truststore) wasn't successful. I may have set it up incorrectly, but the SSLContext only took the first one (keystore with the 1 SSL cert).

Comment: In the debug log BEFORE the `No X.509 for client auth` there should be a decode of the CertificateRequest message showing (depending on Java version) the `Cert Authorities:` or `certificate_authorities:` the server asks for. Make sure the issuer name of a cert in your client-cert's chain matches EXACTLY one of the server's desired CAs. @ewramner+ JSSE nominally takes an array of key and trust managers, but it uses only the first one of a given type; this API was designed to allow for authentication forms other than PKIX, but in practice there are no authentication forms other than PKIX.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So I have actually looked at that. My CA is NOT in the list the server sends my client. So I was initially suspicious of that, but if that is the reason my Java client isn't sending the cert, wouldn't that also cause the Postman request to fail? It's using the same p12 file and calling the same endpoint.

Comment: I don't use Postman, and I don't know if it's written in Java, and if so whether it uses the standard (JSSE) TrustManager implementation. If not, it could easily send the cert even though it shouldn't, and the server might be able to verify more certs than the ones it asks for. I don't know if Postman will show or log this info, but if not you could see it externally with wireshark or similar unless you're using TLS1.3. You can also test manually with `openssl s_client -cert -key` which doesn't implement the name check.

Comment: Also I notice your command to create the P12 didn't specify any intermediate aka chain cert(s). Are you sure this client cert doesn't need any? All public CAs must use at least one, but you didn't say if you're using a public CA; many private CAs also do so to improve safety of the root key. If so, the server probably _asks_ for the root CA which issued the (top) chain cert which should be in your key entry (not just in the store) and sent, but it may be able to rebuild the chain itself if your client doesn't send it (which officially is in violation of the RFCs).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have also built it using the root/intermediate chain. Add that code to the question. The server I'm hitting turns off on the weekends - I'll give that `openssl s_client` command a try on Monday.

Comment: (1) to check the with-chain version is correct _as seen by Java_ do `keytool -list -v -keystore file` -- you should see one `PrivateKeyEntry` with `Certificate[1]` `Certificate[2]` etc. containing the correct data (e.g. names) (2) to be clear, I meant `openssl s_client` with the 'normal' arguments (`-connect host:port` and for many hosts `-servername host` if OpenSSL below 1.1.1 and sometimes other things like a TLS version) _plus_ `-cert certpem -key keypem` and to use chain certs _also_ `-CAfile chainfile` (or `-CApath chaindir` but that's less convenient)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 s_client request looks fine, it successfully connects with the cert and cacerts. See the new update to the question - `Unavailable authentication scheme` in my Java client. Could that be the issue?

Comment: `keytool -list` output looks good as well.

Comment: The _signature on_ your cert doesn't matter; it is the subject-public-key _in_ the cert that matters. You are apparently using TLS1.2 but the server supports RSA-PSS in 1.2 (which is optional) (and so does your JSSE) so if your cert contains an RSA key _and either it or any cert in its chain is issued by a requested CA_ then it is eligible for the rsa_pss_pss_hash rsa_pss_rsae_hash or rsa_pkcs1_hash schemes. _If_ a server sends no CA names, then JSSE does not do the name match, so yes in that case your cert _will_ be tried at least, and most servers will likely accept it. ...

Comment: ... Since the openssl and postman results show this server does accept your Entrust cert if sent, even though it doesn't ask for it, you could write your own KeyManager which does only the algorithm checks and NOT the CA-name check; i.e. start from https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java but have something in the chooseClientAlias/getClientAliases/getAliases chain ignore `issuers`. Actually, you could write a wrapper that only nulls `issuers` and then calls the real code -- that's much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay; it has developed your problem is that when the server requests your client-cert/auth, it specifies a CA list that doesn't include the CA(s?) used by your cert-and-chain, even though when presented with your cert-and-chain the server accepts it. After commenting about writing a wrapper KeyManager, I realized it would be easy enough to test, and the following example works for me to send a client cert different from what the server asked for. I used SSLSocket directly for simplicity, but anything (like OkHttp) using the same SSLContext or SSLSocketFactory should work. Tested in 8u301 (but I can check some others if you want) against OpenSSL commandline, which lets me request client cert for CA X but when I submit a cert from CA Y it only logs the verification error without aborting the connection.

```
public class SO69577136KeyManagerIgnoreCAs  {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        // keystore.p12 pw truststore.p12 pw host port [Y: wrap KM to ignore issuers]
        KeyStore st = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]) ){ st.load(is,args[1].toCharArray()); }
        KeyManagerFactory kf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kf.init(st,  args[1].toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] km = kf.getKeyManagers();
        try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[2]) ){ st.load(is,args[3].toCharArray()); }
        TrustManagerFactory tf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tf.init(st);
        TrustManager[] tm = tf.getTrustManagers();
        
        if( args.length>6 && args[6].startsWith("Y") ){
            X509ExtendedKeyManager orig = (X509ExtendedKeyManager)km[0]; // exception if wrong type
            km[0] = new X509ExtendedKeyManager(){

                @Override
                public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
                    return orig.chooseClientAlias(keyType, null, socket);
                }

                @Override
                public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
                    // not implemented
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
                    return orig.getCertificateChain(alias);
                }

                @Override
                public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
                    // shouldn't actually be used AFAICT but just in case
                    return orig.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers);
                }

                @Override
                public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
                    return orig.getPrivateKey(alias);
                }

                @Override
                public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
                    // not implemented
                    return null;
                }

                public String chooseEngineClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine) {
                    return orig.chooseEngineClientAlias(keyType, null, engine);
                    // could just forward to chooseClientAlias(socket=null), that's what underlying does
                }

                public String chooseEngineServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine) {
                    // not implemented
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(km, tm, null /* default */);
        SSLSocketFactory sf = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(args[4], Integer.parseInt(args[5]));
        ss.startHandshake();
        System.out.println ("successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a true hero. I told my team last week that I would give my next paycheck to whoever figures this out, so I guess I owe you. This worked perfectly for me, and I learned a ton about SSL in the process. Thanks for taking some time to work through this!